# One NSFetchedResultController for UITableview and UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller, magicalrecord

Maybe it's a silly question but I have a feeling that I can improve my project or at least make it more readable.

Here's the deal. I have a `UITableView` populated with data from server. For everything I use `MagicalRecord` and for dealing with `UITableView` I use `NSFetchedResultController`. And up to this point everything is fine. The problem occurs when I try to implement `UISearchDisplayController`. Insted of useing `NSFetchedResultController` I simply fetch data form Core Data and past it to the `NSArray`. Here is the method which I use for sorting:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [Group MR_findAllSortedBy:@"caseInsensitiveName" ascending:YES withPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

An of course all `UITableView` boilerplate code is stuffed with `if` conditions checking type of the `UITableView`.
I think I can use one `NSFetchedResultController` to handle both tasks (populatind both `UITableView`'s) and ommit this `searchResult` array but I'm not sure... So I would appreciate any suggestion, hint or whatever.

One more problem is when I use both `UITableViews` populated from other sources they collide when I enable `sections`. Simply, `UISearchDisplayController.tableView` is covered by `section`s from parent `UITableView`.

### Edit

Here is some code used for handling searching and populating `UITableView`

```
#pragma mark - Table View

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Count sections in FRC
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return [[self.groupsFRC sections] count];
    }
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Count groups in each section of FRC
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];
    } else {
        return [[[self.groupsFRC sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Get reusable cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GroupCell"];

    // If there isn't any create new one
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"GroupCell"];
    }

    Group *group = [self determineGroupInTableViev:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = group.name;

    // Checking if group has been selected earlier
    if ([self.selectedGroups containsObject:@{@"name" : group.name, @"id" : group.cashID}]) {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    } else {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }

    return cell;
}

// Adding checkmark to selected cell
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Group *group = [self determineGroupInTableViev:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Checking if selected cell has accessory view set to checkmark and add group to selected groups array
    if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.selectedGroups addObject:@{@"name" : group.name, @"id" : group.cashID}];
        NSLog(@"%@", self.selectedGroups);
    }
    else if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.selectedGroups removeObject:@{@"name" : group.name, @"id" : group.cashID}];
        NSLog(@"%@", self.selectedGroups);
    }

    // Hiding selection with animation for nice and clean effect
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - Filtering

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [Group MR_findAllSortedBy:@"caseInsensitiveName" ascending:YES withPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;
}

-(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didHideSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Realoading main table view when search result did hide
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: if you are using the Magical record then why you are using the Fechcontroller? Best this is that you a common array and fetch filtered and unfiltered data and reload your tableview

Comment: I use 'NSFetchedResultController' because it provides on-the-run population.

Comment: Give details on your table views and search controller. It may be easier to just use a search bar and update the FRC predicate on changes...

Comment: @Wain I've updated my question with source code. If you'd like something more just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually don't find `UISearchDisplayController` very useful. This is because:

1. I already have a table view
2. The display of the table view cells should be the same while searching and normal
3. I still have to provide all of the table delegate and data source methods
4. I still have to provide the search delegate methods

So, I usually have a single source of data for the table view and manipulate that source based on and entered search criteria.

This works for both FRC or simple Array. For the FRC, edit the fetch request (predicate) and `performFetch:`, everything else is automatic. For the Array, use `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` and reload (I have an original array of the source data, and another array reference used for the table methods. The second array either points to the original array instance or a new instance created from the sort).

In both cases I have a similar amount of methods to using a `UISearchDisplayController`, but there are no `if` statements in the table methods. Any `if` statements and mutation of the data source and handled solely in the search methods (which are call much less frequently).

---

Add a property to the class:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSPredicate *filterPredicate;
```

In the search text changed delegate:

```
if (text.length > 0) {
    self.filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:...];
} else {
    self.filterPredicate = nil;
}

[self refreshFRC];
```

And in the search cancel, just nil the predicate and refresh.

And the refresh:

```
- (void)refreshFRC {
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = ...;

    if (self.filterPredicate != nil) {
        fetch.predicate = self.filterPredicate;
    }

    self.frc.fetchRequest = fetch;

    [self.frc performFetch:...];
}
```

Comment: So, how I can handle this sorting without `UISearchDisplayController`? By providing original table data source?

Comment: Basically, use `UISearchBarDelegate` instead of `UISearchDisplayDelegate` methods, and edit the fetch request for the search content. Technically you could keep the search controller, it's a personal preference thing. The key is editing the fetch request and refetching. Removing the search controller just makes the code cleaner IMHO.

Comment: You mean for the search methods? I assume standard display is all group entities?

Comment: Yes, the main `UITableView` contains all Groups. I don't know what to do with this `UISearchBar` staff... I assume that my `NSFetchedResultController` for main table is good.

Comment: I think I get your point and implemented this using single FRC but I still have a [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983333/repopulating-uitableview-after-search) with repopulating.